# How min(numeric string) works in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions

```
select min(val) from (select '10026096' as val union select '1002793' as val);
```

The above sql query return the following output:

```
MIN(VAL)
10026096
```

Please help me understand why snowflake is giving numerically bigger number as output amongst the two. How does it process numeric string in min function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping data using correct data type is the key and INT != STRING.

```
1 0 0 2 6 0 9 6
= = = = <
1 0 0 2 7 9 3
```

Therefore string `10026096` is lower than `1002793`.

---

```
SELECT '10026096' < '1002793'
     , 10026096 < 1002793;
```

Output:

| '10026096' < '1002793' | 10026096 < 1002793 |
| --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE |

Comment: this column in table has values like '123' and '123_345' . That's why keeping it as string. Thanks for your answer. It solves the doubt.